# How do I create a sub domain for an existing app service in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, subdomain

I am trying to create a new sub domain for an existing app service (let's call it appservice1) in Azure but am getting the following error below.

I have created a second app service, where I have a number of APIs that I want to expose but I want them in a sub domain of an existing app service (e.g. appservice1.azurewebsites.net). So I want to be able to call them using api.appservice1.azurewebsites.net. At the moment, I can only call them using apiappservice2.azurewebsites.net.

I've created a DNS zone in Azure for my first app service i.e. appservice1 and added the CNAME and TXT records it asked to be added. It's been a couple of days but no joy. Can someone tell me how this can be done?

Thank you in advance.

[Add custom domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2ZJ0.png)

[DNS zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKA6J.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't create an additional level to the App Service domain.

Comment: Ok that's a shame. Thanks